# utorrent clogs normal browsing

Tags: utorrent

I don't use torrents often so this may be just something simple I overlooked. When using uTorrent (haven't tried any other clients for now), although download+upload speed are not 10% of my connection, the browsing speed goes to hell (extremelly slow).

Anyone knows what could  be the most probably cause ?

Platform: XP SP2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What OS are you on? If it's XP, try [this TCPIP.sys patch](http://hwrms.com/blog/?p=17).

The problem is, XP (and pre-SP2 Vista) only allowed 10 "half open" TCP/IP connections - a half open connection is one trying to connect, and an open one is one that's connected. Normally this isn't an issue, but bittorrent makes a LOT of connections - seriously slowing down attempts to make any more.

---

Edit by ldigas: [patch for Windows XP SP2 (from RC2 upwards) or Windows 2003 Server SP1 beta](http://www.lvllord.de/?url=tools)

Comment: Yes, more than the bandwidth, there is a problem of number of simultaneous connections.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I see this is for xp sp3. Is there some solution for sp2 (which I'm currently running). I wouldn't like to go to sp3 for now.

Comment: There should be, somewhere, but I'm afraid it's been far too long for me to recall where :(

Comment: Found it. Thanks Phoshi ! Hope you don't mind me messing with your answer.

Comment: Certainly not! Thanks for adding the right stuff :)

Answer (score 3):

Look into a traffic shaping solution. I have been using [cfosspeed](http://www.cfos.de/speed/cfosspeed_e.htm) for a few years, on XP and now Windows 7 x64.

That said, I still find reducing my utorrent number of connections to 50 (active seeded torrents can still be 1000) helps a lot - with or without traffic shaping.